Configuration help triggering build with wildcard branch name
Sounds simple, I know, but having trouble.  Any help/guidance/epiphany appreciated!
We want to automatically trigger a build on a specific branch pattern.  I have been reading Working with Feature Branches | TeamCity On-Premises Documentation (jetbrains.com) and I think following it closely, but no joy.
We have +:refs/heads/MVF-* specified in Branch specification on Edit VCS Root.
For Default Branch same screen, we have refs/heads/master .
In Branch filter on vcs trigger, we have
+:*
-:
When triggering manually, getting “Builds in the default branch are disabled and build configuration doesn't have any other branches. If you run a build, it will fail.”  Msg is correct - fails. :-)
Running 2023.11.1 (build 147412) Against Atlassian Bitbucket v6.7.1
Expected the build to run without an error.  There is indeed an MVF-JoeTestTC branch in BB

Why do you exclude the default branch from the specification pattern? A what branch do you trigger when getting this error?

Probably because I am clueless?  :-)  Goal is to automatically trigger whenever a branch of the pattern MVF-* is updated.  Meaning one of our MVFs has new commits, and we want to build it.  We exclude the default cuz we dont want to build it, but default branch is mandatory.  It was as good a branch to put there as anything.

@AlexanderPletnev  Please followup if/when you have time?  Thank you so much ...
